# Place popup-score at enemy position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas, text

I’d like to place a popup-score at the position where an enemy has been destroyed. I'm developing a 2D-game in Unity3D.

So far the popup-score gets rendered inside of the canvas but the position seems to have an offset. How do I place the popup-score at the position of the destroyed enemy exactly?

This is the c#-class that fades the score:

```
public class FloatAndFade : MonoBehaviour {

Text text;

public float fadeDuration = 2.0f;
public float speed = 2.0f;

void Start () {
    text = this.GetComponent<Text>();
    StartCoroutine(Fade());
}

public IEnumerator Fade () {

    float fadeSpeed = (float)1.0 / fadeDuration;
    Color c = text.color;

    for (float t = 0.0f; t < 1.0f; t += Time.deltaTime * fadeSpeed) {
        c.a = Mathf.Lerp(1, 0, t);          
        text.color = c;
        yield return true;      }

    Destroy (this.gameObject);
}

void Update() {
    this.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

This is the FloatScore-method that places the popup-score inside of the canvas:

```
void FloatScore () {
    GameObject popupScore = (GameObject)Instantiate (floatScore);

    popupScore.transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(this.transform.position);

    popupScore.transform.SetParent (canvas.transform, false);
}
```

This is the gameplay with the popup-score:

[image]

These are the settings for the canvas:

[image]

Comment: I don't get it. The code looks ok. Can you show an example of the score having an offset?

Comment: I updated my question (sorry for the small picture I hope it helps).

Comment: `this.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed);` this snippet in the Update moves the text up before disappearing. Is that what you mean by offset?

Comment: No. The text shall appear exactly at the position of the explosion (where enemy has been destroyed). In the image you can see that there is an offset between the explosions and the score-text.

Comment: `WorldToScreenPoint` is not enough. You also need `RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle`. See the duplicate.

Comment: I found this tutorial and now it works like a charm: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1dsHaw4ydVQ